# How to see if openAI (node js) createModeration response "flagged" is true

Tags: javascript, node.js, openai-api

Using the OpenAI createModeration feature, I am trying to see if the string gets flagged or not.

I request the API by using this:
`

```
const mod = await openai.createModeration({
      input: 'Some text to be flagged', // isn't actually this that would get flagged
});
console.log(mod.data.results)
```

When I log the resposne (and it's flagged) I get this:

```
[
  {
      hate: 0.057017914950847626,
      'hate/threatening': 0.0013999055372551084,
      'self-harm': 1.523021175842132e-8,
      sexual: 0.000011195417755516246,
      'sexual/minors': 4.2277463307982543e-8,
      violence: 0.8440001010894775,
      'violence/graphic': 1.2527605974810285e-7
    },
    flagged: true
  }
]
```

`

However, if I try to get the "flagged" option by doing `mod.data.results.flagged` it returns unidentified.

Comment: Please verify and fix the return object, it is missing something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mod.data.results` is an array of objects. To get the first `flagged` value specify `mod.data.results[0].flagged` (or `mod.data.results[0]?.flagged` to account for an empty array)

**UPDATE** Actually something is not correct with your example object, it is missing a curly bracket.